# Proper way to use sql commit

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have code as follows:

```
try:
    conn = db_connection()
    cur = conn.cursor()

    if is_address_changed(vehicle, conn, cur):
        update_vehicle_address(vehicle, conn, cur)
        conn.commit()

    if is_price_changed(vehicle, conn, cur):
        update_vehicle(vehicle, conn, cur)
        insert_vehicle_price(vehicle, conn, cur)
        conn.commit()

    conn.close()
except Exception as e:
    capture_error(str(e))
```

Thus, in my code I have `conn.commit()` in both `if statements`.

Is this correct approach? Or could I add only one above `conn.close()`

What would happen in one and in other case?

Comment: one above close

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way that the above code works is that the behavior would be exactly the same if you had a single call to `commit()` above the call to `close()`. So to make the code more readable it would be better to have a single call. This would also make it easier to modify the code without forgetting the call to `commit()`.

In terms of how database code should be written, it's usually best to commit as late as possible - right before closing if possible. This means that if something goes wrong you can roll back all the data easily. Exceptions would be if you know explicitly that you want some part of the update to go through even if a later part fails.